# Why does my setTimeout not stop when I clear?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, settimeout

I am trying to stop my Timeout when I received data back from my ajax post. However, I get the data back, it updates my html, but the timer is still going. What's going wrong?

```
function getResponse() {

var i = 0;
var reply = null;
var myTimer;

while (i < 24 && reply == null) {
  (function(i) {
        myTimer = setTimeout(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/getResponse',
            data: "123456",
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("HERE data2 " + data);
                if(data != "" || data != null){
                    reply = data;
                    document.getElementById("responseText").innerHTML = reply;
                    clearTimeout(myTimer);
                }
            },
            error: function (error) {
                document.getElementById("responseText").innerHTML = error;
                console.log(error);
            }

        });           

    }, 5000 * i)
  })(i++)
}
```

Comment: can you `console. log` myTimer  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are overwriting your global `myTimer` variable in each iteration of the while loop. So every time you are doing `clearTimeout(myTimer)` you are just clearing the timeout of the last *setTimeout* that is run when `i` becomes `23` and not for setTimeout created in the previous 22 iterations of the while loop. You actually have to declare the myTimer variable inside the IIFE in the while loop like the following to clearTimeout for all the 23 setTimeouts created during the while loop:

```
function getResponse() {

var i = 0;
var reply = null;
// var myTimer;

while (i < 24 && reply == null) {
  (function(i) {
        var myTimer = setTimeout(function() { // Declare myTimer here
        $.ajax({
            url: '/getResponse',
            data: "123456",
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("HERE data2 " + data);
                if(data != "" || data != null){
                    reply = data;
                    document.getElementById("responseText").innerHTML = reply;
                    clearTimeout(myTimer);
                }
            },
            error: function (error) {
                document.getElementById("responseText").innerHTML = error;
                console.log(error);
            }

        });           

    }, 5000 * i)
  })(i++)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is cleared. But you are calling your function over and over (23 times) and every time you are setting new timeout and clearing him again.